# Problems with nested Predicate in FOL

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, logic-translation

In my teacher's lecture, its have a problems like this: execute statements based on the following base predicates

- $L(x)$: $x$ is a logician
- $f(x)$: a function that return values is a friend of $x$

So, performs this sentences to logic predicate:

> There are some people who are friends of $x$ who are also logicians

The results is: $\exists x L(f(x))$ but its not supposed like this $\exists x, y L(x) \land y = f(x)$?

I dont know why but is this the same or **not**? Then can I replace nested predicate instead of $\land$, too?

Comment: Maybe  ∃x, y L(y) ∧ y = f(x) because the friend of x is a Logician.

Comment: yes, but semantically its the same things, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\exists x L(f(x))$$

and $$\exists x, y \ L(x) \land y = f(x)$$

are not equivalent:  in the second statement, you are saying that $x$ is a logician, but it should be that the *friend* of $x$ is a logician.  So, what you *can* do is:

$$\exists x, y \ L(y) \land y = f(x)$$

and that statement is equivalent to

$$\exists x L(f(x))$$

Comment: ok,now i got it just because the f(x) is the function, its return an object therefore its can be placed inside the predicate L(x)? and the second statement that you said its was right, sorry for my grammar was wrong when translate its.Just that i've a bit confuse when i see in venn diagram, the result second statement that you fixed for me is the set of intersection of L(x) and f(x) and  the L(f(x)) statement the f(x) is inside the L(x)

Comment: @chew Yes, exactly: $f(x)$ is an object, and can thus be used as an argument to a predicate.